# Javascript json returning undefined

Tags: javascript, json, express

So I'm trying to grab some data from a json object through a for in loop and it keeps returning undefined. Here is my code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request('https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=############', function (error, response, body) {
    json = JSON.parse(body);
    var popular_tags = [];

    for (var key in json['data']){
      tag = JSON.stringify(key['tags'])
        popular_tags.push(tag)  
    }
    console.log(popular_tags)

    res.render('index', {title: body });
  });
});
```

This is the output I recieve:

```
[ undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ]
```

However, when I try

```
var popular_tags = [];
popular_tags.push(json['data'][0]['tags'])
console.log(popular_tags)
```

It will print out what I want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line to

```
tag = JSON.stringify(json['data'][key]['tags'])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
for (var key in json['data'])
```

the `key` is iterating through the attribute names of the object `json.data`, and is thus a *string*. Thus, `key['tags']` is `undefined` as strings generally don't have an attribute `tags`. Things snowball from there.

The general idiom is:

```
for (var key in json.data) {
  if (json.data.hasOwnProperty(key) {
    var item = json.data[key];
    // ...
  }
}
```

The `hasOwnProperty` thing is the protection against someone injecting something in a prototype of whatever you're iterating. For example, if someone did something silly like `Object.prototype.breakAllCode = true`, `"breakAllCode"` would show up as a `key` on whatever you were iterating.